# Code works fine on win7, but there are problems on OSX

Tags: macos, r, statistics, plot

i have problems to perform my R-Code in OSX.
That's my code:

```
i <- 1
while (i <= 20000) {
  repeat{
    z1=((runif(1,0,1)*2)-1)
    z2=((runif(1,0,1)*2)-1)
    h=z1**2+z2**2
    if((h > 0) && (h <= 1)){break}
   }
  x[i] <- z1
  y[i] <- z2
  q[i] <- h

  i <- i + 1
} 

j <- 1
while (j <= 20000) {
  h=sqrt((-2*ln(q[j]))/q[j])
  p[j] <- h
  j <- j + 1
}

a=x*p
b=y*p
points(a,b, pch=c(20,20),col=c("dark green","red"),cex=0.6)
```

When I initialize x,y,q,p and use the log, it works.

But why are there those errors, but why?

```
error in x[i] <- z1: object 'x' not fund
error: no function for "ln" fund
error: object 'x' not fund
error: object 'y' not fund
```

Comment: The assignment to `x` (`x[i] <- z1`) should not work under any circumstance, whether Win7 or OS X. Please make your question more clear as to what the problem is.

Comment: Because if they are not initialized, they do not exist. And if they do not exist, you cannot assign a value to them. Did this run on win7? I doubt it...

Comment: yes i swear this code runs on win7 without an error....

Comment: Hmmm, the R interpreter on win7 is not different, so it should not...

Comment: I would be curious to see how your code runs on a Win7 machine.  Perhaps try this.  1. Close R on your Win machine. 2. Copy the code from your post above. 3. Open R on your Win machine and paste your R code into it.  I suggest this because sometimes I have tried a bunch of stuff in R to get code to run and it only runs in the end because of accumulated earlier code stored in the same open R session from previous attempts.

Comment: As others noted, I highly doubt this is a difference between Windows and OSX. If you confirm that, do you mind changing your title to better reflect your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another approach. Your code should generally be faster if you reduce the number of times you need to do things iteratively. Specifically, all of your `runif(1,0,1)` calls can be replaced by one big vector of `runif()` values, then subset the vector based on that.

I used @Mark Miller's function as the starting point and made the following modifications. Note, this can be improved further if the oversampler kept the good values from the previous set of random numbers and only filled in until `n` was reached, but this is pretty fast regardless. For the speed comparisons, I took his code verbatim and wrapped it in `fun2 <- function() {...}`

```
fun1 <- function(n, oversample = 1.50){
  #oversample
  over <- ceiling(n * oversample)
  goodvars <- NA
  while (length(goodvars) < n){
    z1 <- runif(over,-1,1)
    z2 <- runif(over,-1,1)
    h <- z1^2 + z2^2  
    goodvars <- which(h > 0 & h < 1)
  }
  goodvars <- goodvars[1:n]
  x <- z1[goodvars]
  y <- z2[goodvars]
  q <- h[goodvars]
  p <- sqrt((-2 * log(q)) / q)
  a <- x * p
  b <- y * p
  return(cbind(a,b))
 }

##Mark's code put into a function
fun2 <- function() {
  i <- 1

  x <- rep(NA, 20)
  y <- rep(NA, 20)
  q <- rep(NA, 20)
  p <- rep(NA, 20)

  while (i <= 20) {

    repeat{
      z1=((runif(1,0,1)*2)-1)
      z2=((runif(1,0,1)*2)-1)
      h=z1**2+z2**2
      if((h > 0) & (h <= 1)){break}
    }
    x[i] <- z1
    y[i] <- z2
    q[i] <- h

    i <- i + 1
  } 

  j <- 1
  while (j <= 20) {

    h=sqrt((-2*log(q[j]))/q[j])

    p[j] <- h

    j <- j + 1
  }

  a=x*p
  b=y*p
}

#Do some speed checking with rbenchmark. Also checkout compiler package for some free speed
library(compiler)
library(rbenchmark)
#Compile functions to see improvements
cfun1 <- cmpfun(fun1)
cfun2 <- cmpfun(fun2)
#run benchmark tests
benchmark(fun1(n = 20), fun2(), cfun1(n = 20), cfun2(),
          replications = 1000,
          columns=c("test", "elapsed", "relative"),
          order = "elapsed")
```

And the results

```
           test elapsed  relative
3 cfun1(n = 20)   0.042  1.000000
1  fun1(n = 20)   0.055  1.309524
4       cfun2()   0.407  9.690476
2        fun2()   0.882 21.000000
```

Starting with a new R session, copying and pasting the code above does not return an error. Here's an example:

```
test <- fun1(n = 1000)
plot(test)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: but i get the error, "object fun2 not found, error in cmpfun(fun2)...do you know why???

Comment: @Chase - Also change to `((runif(over,0,1) * 2) - 1)` to `runif(over,-1,1)`

Comment: @jeffrey - sorry, I defined fun2 as Mark Miller's code put into function form. I added it above so you should be able to copy/paste all and see the results. I tested the compiler package to see if/what speed bumps you can get from byte compiling the functions...it's essentially free speed!

Comment: Also note that the speed tests shown above will get slower and slower for mark's code as that loop is going to have to be called many more times, the function I put together should scale pretty well to large n

Comment: still got some errors...I put 20 for all and then I try to plot that with plot(a,b)...then I get: unexpected numeric constant in "fun <- function", object "oversample" not found, error in runif and error: no function to break off jump to Top Level....mhhh do you know why?

Comment: @jeffrey - bah, man I'm sloppy today. I had an extra `(` in there...should be fixed now.

Comment: @Chase sorry, but I still get these errors...perhaps I did a mistake...I have replaced all "n" by the amouunt of random numbers I want to generate....and then I tried to visualize a and b by plot(a,b)...I think the plot must look like a normal distribution from above...but that is what I want to show

Comment: @jeffrey - maybe you still have something that's not updated in your environment that is messing things up. Try running `rm(list=ls())` to clear your environment. To be clear - this will remove everything, so save anything of importance first. Alternatively, close R and restart. I've added an example above to get the plot I think you want.

Comment: @jeffrey - there's a non-zero probability of `h` not meeting the criteria defined above, and R is much more adept at generating a longer list of random numbers once than it is generating smaller subsets of random number many times. By setting the `oversample`, we tell R to generate more than enough numbers, hoping that the proportion that fit the criteria is greater than `n`. So if `n = 10` and we over sample by 50%, we're telling R to generate a vector of 15 random numbers, and hope that 10 of them meet the criteria for `h`. If not, it will rinse, wash, and repeat until it gets it right.

Answer (score 2):

Does this do what you want?  I:

1. added vectors to store x, y, q, and p.
2. changed ln to log
3. added a plot(a,b) statement.
4. changed 20000 to 20 for debugging purposes.

I do not have a Mac.

```
i <- 1

x <- rep(NA, 20)
y <- rep(NA, 20)
q <- rep(NA, 20)
p <- rep(NA, 20)

while (i <= 20) {

repeat{
    z1=((runif(1,0,1)*2)-1)
    z2=((runif(1,0,1)*2)-1)
    h=z1**2+z2**2
if((h > 0) & (h <= 1)){break}
 }
x[i] <- z1
y[i] <- z2
q[i] <- h

i <- i + 1
} 

j <- 1
while (j <= 20) {

h=sqrt((-2*log(q[j]))/q[j])

p[j] <- h

j <- j + 1
}

a=x*p
b=y*p
plot(a,b)
points(a,b, pch=c(20,20),col=c("dark green","red"),cex=0.6)
```

Comment: +1, but it still feels like C code written in R. This could probably be reduced to a line of 5 by useing vectorization and apply style loops.

Answer (score 2):

You can't be starting from a fresh empty workspace on Windows. The '`x`' object must already exist, or you'd get the error there too. Do `ls()` in Windows and OSX and see if there is an '`x`'. I'd put money on there being one in Windows but not OSX.

Comment: yeah, your absolutely right :-) so I must initialize x one time, then I can use it in that workspace?

Comment: Probably. When you start R it loads objects from a .RData file, and when you quit it asks if you want to save your current objects back to a .RData file. Basic stuff!